# React Redux thunk - Chaining dispatches

Tags: async-await, react-redux, es6-promise, fetch-api, redux-thunk

Currently i'm building an application that is heavily dependant on API calls. The api calls are done within Redux actions with Thunk middleware like so:

```
export const brand_fetchAll = () => {
return dispatch => {
    fetch(apiURL+'brand')
        .then(response => {return response.json();})
        .then(content => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'BRAND_STORE_ALL',
                content
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}}
```

In my component, i'm first fetching the data through separate actions. After that i'm opening up an editor:

```
// A component method
editModeOn(){
    // Fetch data
    this.props.dispatch(campaign_fetchAll());
    this.props.dispatch(brand_fetchAll());
    // Open editor
    this.props.dispatch(page_editModeOn());
}
```

Right now the editor opens before the api calls have completed, so no data is being shown. It's possible to chain the dispatches within the actions, but i want to keep the modularity, so i don't have to create hundreds of custom API calls. Ideally what i want is to chain them using something like promises:

```
    // A component method
editModeOn(){
    this.props.dispatch(campaign_fetchAll().then(brand_fetchAll()).then(page_editModeOn());
}
```

Unfortunately i didn't yet get that to work. I hope someone can help me out. If you need more information i'm happy to hand it over. Better ideas are also very welcome :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Would a callback function be an option for you?

So update your code to be;

```
export const brand_fetchAll = (callback) => {
return dispatch => {
    fetch(apiURL+'brand')
        .then(response => {return response.json();})
        .then(content => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'BRAND_STORE_ALL',
                content
            });

            callback();
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}}

// A component method
editModeOn(){
    // Fetch data
    this.props.dispatch(campaign_fetchAll());
    this.props.dispatch(brand_fetchAll(() => {
        // Open editor
        this.props.dispatch(page_editModeOn());
    }));        
}
```

You are chaining the callback onto the end of the api call success, however, you are not tightly coupling what it is as you are passing this in depending on the usage.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! This actually works perfectly! Sometimes things can be so simple :) You saved my day.